Could not find gradle-8.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.1)
I'm using
Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-232.10300.40.2321.11567975, built on March 13, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.9+0--11185874 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4050M
Cores: 16
Registry:
    ide.experimental.ui=true

I want to create an empty project.

I get this error message:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle-8.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.3.1/gradle-8.3.1.jar
   > Could not find gradle-settings-api-8.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-settings-api:8.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-settings-api/8.3.1/gradle-settings-api-8.3.1.jar
   > Could not find lint-model-31.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:31.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-model/31.3.1/lint-model-31.3.1.jar
   > Could not find builder-8.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:8.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/8.3.1/builder-8.3.1.jar



As far as I know, there is no Gradle with version 8.3.1.
Gradle releases
Try to change your distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties file to
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip

